# Linux PCI driver stops working after DMA

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a custom PCIe device in **two** desktop computers running RHEL 7.3, linux kernel 3.10

- The first computer has an older motherboard with an older AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 B95 Processor. On this computer everything works well.
- The second computer has a current motherboard with a Intel Core i7-7700 CPU.

So on that second computer, the PCIe device/driver would work fine **until** DMA is started. DMA operations would work for a minute or so, then the device/driver would stop working, meaning reading any BAR register return 0xFFFFFFF, and DMA is stopped.
**NOW**, if i remove the driver module, then do a pci remove followed by pci rescan and reload driver module, everything will work fine forever after.

I have a feeling it is an IOMMU security issue but am not sure how to troubleshoot that. Any idea what would cause a PCI device driver to work properly only after a rescan ?

Comment: What is the destination address of the DMA? is it RAM memory?

Comment: Yes, the DMA is from device memory to RAM memory only.

Comment: Iommu will not allow you to do transfers to secure regions, otherwise it's not an iommu issue. I would check your device in a sense of compliance to PCIe specifications.